# ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation' from 'sklearn.decomposition._online_lda'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I'm facing error whenever I import any Tree module from sklearn. Sample code below

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
model = ExtraTreesRegressor()
model.fit(X,y)
```

The first time I run the code I get this error -

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'LatentDirichletAllocation' from 'sklearn.decomposition._online_lda' (C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition_online_lda.cp37-win_amd64.pyd)
```

After that, whenever I run the same code, I get the following error -

```
AttributeError: type object 'sklearn.tree.criterion.array' has no attribute 'reducecython'
```

The same code worked well before but suddenly it has stopped working for me

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing scikit-learn as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Try to install the package from `conda-forge` channel: `conda install scikit-learn -c conda-forge`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a problem with conda install sklearn version 0.22 as questioned in this [issues](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/663).

Try `pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: You should not do that since Utkarsh Kant is using `conda`. It will be a mess afterwords.

Answer (score 0):

Update the scikit-learn, most precisely version 0.22.1